# Curve fitting with large number of data points

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, curve-fitting, jupyter

this is quite a specific problem I was hoping the community could help me out with. Thanks in advance.

So I have 2 sets of data, one is experimental and the other is based off of an equation. I am trying to fit my data points to this curve and hence obtain the missing variables I am interested in. Namely, a and b in the Ebfit function.

Here is the code:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as spys
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

time = [60,220,520,1840]
Moment = [0.64227262,0.468318916,0.197100772,0.104512508]

Temperature = 25                                # Bake temperature in degrees C
Nb = len(Moment)                                           # Number of bake measurements
Baketime_a = time                  #[s]
N_Device = 10000                                    # No. of devices considered in the array
T_ambient = 273 + Temperature
kt = 0.0256*(T_ambient/298)                         # In units of eV
f0 = 1e9                                            # Attempt frequency


def Ebfit(x,a,b):
    Eb_mean = a*(0.0256/kt)                       # Eb at bake temperature
    Eb_sigma = b*Eb_mean
    Foursigma =  4*Eb_sigma
    Eb_a = np.linspace(Eb_mean-Foursigma,Eb_mean+Foursigma,N_Device)
    dEb = Eb_a[1] - Eb_a[0]
    pdfEb_a = spys.norm.pdf(Eb_a,Eb_mean,Eb_sigma)

    ## Retention Time

    DMom = np.zeros(len(x),float)
    tau = (1/f0)*np.exp(Eb_a)
    for bb in range(len(x)):
        DMom[bb]= (1 - 2*(sum(pdfEb_a*(1 - np.exp(np.divide(-x[bb],tau))))*dEb))
    return DMom

a = 30
b = 0.10

params,extras = curve_fit(Ebfit,time,Moment)

x_new = list(range(0,2000,1))
y_new = Ebfit(x_new,params[0],params[1])

plt.plot(time,Moment, 'o', label = 'data points')
plt.plot(x_new,y_new, label = 'fitted curve')
plt.legend()
```

The main problem I am having is that the fitting of the data to the function does not work when I use large number of points. In the above code When I use the 4 points (time & moment), this code works fine.

I get the following values for *a* and *b*.

array([ 29.11832766,   0.13918353])

The expected values for a is (23-50) and b is (0.06 - 0.15). So these values are within the acceptable range. This is the corresponding plot:  [image: Plot 1]

However, when I use my actual experimental normalized data with about 500 points.

EDIT: This data:

**Normalized Data**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/64zke4wckxc1r75/Normalized%20Data.csv?dl=0

Raw Data

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ojgse5ibp59r8nw/Data1.csv?dl=0

I get the following values and plot for *a* and *b* which are out of the acceptable range,

array([-13.76687781, -12.90494196]) 
 [image: Plot 2]

I know these values are wrong and if I were to do it manually (slowly adjusting values to obtain the proper fit) it would be around *a=30.1* and *b=0.09*. And when plotted looks as such:  [image: Plot 3]

I have tried changing the initial guess values for *a & b*, other sets of experimental data as well and other suggestions in similar threads. None seem to work for me. Any help you can provide is appreciated. Thanks.

.
.
.
.

***ADDITIONAL INFORMATION***

The model I am trying to  fit the data to comes from the following equation: 
[image: Equation]

where Dmom = 1 - 2*Psw

*a* is the Eb value while *b* is the Sigma value where, Eb has a range of values determined by the probability density function and 4 times of the sigma values (i.e. Foursigma). This distribution is then summed up to use for the final equation.

Comment: Your Google Drive link appears to be restricted. Is this intentional?

Comment: @VlasSokolov hey sorry about that. I have updated the link. Please try again.

Comment: The moment data in the file range from -3e-5 to 1.65e-5, but in your fit to a 500-point dataset the ranges go up to one. Does this explain the fit discrepancy? Do you normalize the data somewhere in between fitting them and plotting them on-screen?

Comment: @VlasSokolov. Oh Im terribly sorry again. And yes you are right. I have to use normalized data. So it should be from 0 to 1. I have updated with the correct data. Thanks for the help mate.

Comment: Two more nitpicks. 1) Some of the values in the time data are repeating, looks like rounding issue - you only keep three significant digits. 2) The last time value in the csv file is blank.

Comment: @VlasSokolov Hmm... I guess excel cut off my significant figures when I copied the data. But I think the repeated values and rounding issue shouldn't be a problem as long as they follow the trend I want yeah? Removed the last point as well. Anyways, I have attached both the normalized and raw data if you want to refer to both.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128851/discussion-between-vlas-sokolov-and-xplodnow).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you do need to play around with the initial guesses for `a` and `b` after all. Perhaps the function you're fitting is not very well behaved, which is why it's so prone to fail for intitial guesses away from the global minumum. That being said, here's a working example of how to fit your data:

```
import pandas as pd
data_df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
time = data_df['Time since start, Time [s]'].values
moment = data_df['Signal X direction, Moment [emu]'].values

params, extras = curve_fit(Ebfit, time, moment, p0=[40, 0.3])
```

Yields the values of `a` and `b` of:

```
In [6]: params
Out[6]: array([ 30.47553689,   0.08839412])
```

Which results in a nicely aligned fit of a function.

```
x_big = np.linspace(1, 1800, 2000)
y_big = Ebfit(x_big, params[0], params[1])

plt.plot(time, moment, 'o', alpha=0.5, label='all points')
plt.plot(x_big, y_big, label = 'fitted curve')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: fits]